# iPhone apps transfers?

Tags: iphone

If you have an iPhone 3G and you upgrade to an iPhone 3GS, can you transfer your apps across phones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you just have to authorize the new phone on your iTunes account.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to sync your old iPhone to your iTunes, then sync your new one, I would think.

Comment: No problem, good luck to you.

Answer (score -1):

It automatically does it for you when you log in with the same Apple ID from any iPhone.